# Shippo API Integration: Status returns as "ERROR" even if "VALID"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, shippo

I've integrated Shippo with my Ruby on Rails Spree platform. Everything seems to be working great, except that when I go to create a transaction to print shipping labels, I get an error in the response.

Here's my response:

`#<Transaction:0x3feee363470c[id=1b419434531e4b43b438c54b93e2a9f5]
{"object_state"=>"VALID", "status"=>"ERROR", "object_created"=>"2017-06-27T23:11:54.567Z", "object_updated"=>"2017-06-27T23:11:55.330Z", "object_id"=>"xxxx", "object_owner"=>"----@gmail.com", "test"=>true, "rate"=>{"object_id"=>"xxxx", "amount"=>"6.52", "currency"=>"USD", "amount_local"=>"6.52", "currency_local"=>"USD", "provider"=>"USPS", "servicelevel_name"=>"Priority Mail", "servicelevel_token"=>"usps_priority", "carrier_account"=>"xxxx"}, "tracking_number"=>"", "tracking_status"=>nil, "tracking_history"=>[], "tracking_url_provider"=>"", "label_url"=>"", "commercial_invoice_url"=>nil, "messages"=>[#<Hashie::Mash code="" source="USPS" text="Request failed. Please try again or contact Shippo support at support@goshippo.com.">], "order"=>nil, "metadata"=>"", "parcel"=>"xxxx"}->#<Shippo::API::ApiObject created=2017-06-27 23:11:54 UTC id="1b419434531e4b43b438c54b93e2a9f5" owner="xxxx@xxxx.com" state=#<Shippo::API::Category::State:0x007fddbca5a2e8 @name=:state, @value=:valid> updated=2017-06-27 23:11:55 UTC>`

Here's the code used to create the label:

```
def self.createLabel(order_info)
    shipping_info = order_info.shipping_address
    stock_location = order_info.store.stock_location

address_from = {
  :name => stock_location.name,
  :company => order_info.store.name,
  :street1 => stock_location.address1,
  :street2 => stock_location.address2,
  :city => stock_location.city,
  :state => "#{Spree::State.find(stock_location.state_id)}",
  :zip => stock_location.zipcode,
  :country => "#{Spree::Country.find(stock_location.country_id)}",
  :phone => stock_location.phone,
}

address_to = {
    :name => "#{shipping_info.firstname} #{shipping_info.lastname}",
    :company => shipping_info.company,
    :street1 => shipping_info.address1,
    :street2 => shipping_info.address2,
    :city => shipping_info.city,
    :state => "#{Spree::State.find(shipping_info.state_id)}",
    :zip => shipping_info.zipcode,
    :country => "#{Spree::Country.find(shipping_info.country_id)}",
    :phone => shipping_info.phone,
    :email => order_info.email
}
parcel = {
    :length => getLength(order_info),
    :width => getWidth(order_info),
    :height => getHeight(order_info),
    :distance_unit => :m,
    :weight => getWeight(order_info),
    :mass_unit => :lb
}

shipment = {
    :address_from => address_from,
    :address_to => address_to,
    :parcels => parcel
}

#Shippo Carrier ids
@ups = Rails.application.secrets.ups_shippo_id
@usps = Rails.application.secrets.usps_shippo_id
transaction = Shippo::Transaction.create(
    :shipment => shipment,
    :carrier_account => "#{@usps}",
    :servicelevel_token => "usps_priority",
    :label_file_type => "PDF",
    :async => false
)
end
```

Has anyone run into this issue before? I've looked at their documentation and cannot find any reason for a `"status"=>"ERROR"` message, when the `"object_state"=>"VALID"`.

I'm happy to post more code if needed. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend checking the version of the API that you're using compared the version of the Ruby gem you're using. The Ruby client wrapper is designed to be used with the most recent version of the API, so if you're still at the implementation phase, I'd recommend updating the most recent version of the Shippo API.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this bug? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found with lots of trial and error, was that the products I was sending to Shippo actually exceeded the weight the shipping carrier would allow in a package. (This was because my database was a bunch of dummy data). Be sure to be setting your measurement units as well, here:

```
    parcel = {
      :length => getLength(order_info),
      :width => getWidth(order_info),
      :height => getHeight(order_info),
      :distance_unit => :m,
      :weight => getWeight(order_info),
      :mass_unit => :lb
    }
```

After changing the data in my database to have reasonable weights on the products, this error went away.